# How to move a node imported from Blender

Tags: scenekit, blender

I am trying to move around an animated 3D model (from Blender) in Scene Kit.

I can rotate my model with this code:

`let ship = scene.rootNode.childNode(withName: "ship", recursively: true)!
ship.skinner!.skeleton!.runAction(SCNAction.repeatForever(SCNAction.rotateBy(x: 0, y: 2, z: 0, duration: 1)))`

But this code doesn't move it around:

```
ship.skinner!.skeleton!.runAction(SCNAction.repeatForever(moveForward))
```

Additionally, I can't drag my model around in the .scn file (unlike my other unanimated models). My animated model seems to have extra attributes:
[screenshot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CuR8x.png)
How can I move my animated model around in space?

Comment: 0


I wasn't running the action on the desired object (the armature).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as your model loaded correctly into the node, it's just a matter of moving the node (or rotating it as you did) and it behaves just like other nodes.

A runAction.repeat of moveForward is going to repeat the same move - say SCNVector3(5, 0, 0) - but it's the same every time so once it gets there, it's not going to move any further.  Some options are to loop it and call runAction moveTo and increment your moveForward vector each time, or use the physics engine and add velocity, etc.